# How to reuse objects in Request scope with (any) injector ? between different scopes

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, code-injection, inject

I'm using Google Guice 3.0 and RequestScoped.

I understand that for the same Request, Guice will give me the same instance.

But, it will not **reuse the instance** for different Request, even if other (older) instances are out of scope.

Is there a way to reuse a discarded instance?

Let's say that the creation of the object instance is heavy. I would like to do not dispose of the instance, but keep that (for a time) and reuse it in a future request.

**Is it possible?** Is there an implementation of such scope for Guice?
If not it is feasible to change the DI.

best regards
and thanks for the help.

Comment: I was thinking to resolve the issue with object pooling or cache
Like. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool. any hint?

Comment: Maybe I haven't understood you correctly, but it seems that you are looking for @Singleton scope.

Comment: Not really; The object is not thread safe. I need more than one instance

Comment: Then, I guess, Guice does not have such option by default. You can try to implement your own scope, using, as you mentioned, something like `commons-pool` as a backend.